embed Live chat on my website with translator
Is there any live chat system which has a translator? for example: my staff received a user's message, and the user doesn't type english, but this system translated it into english automatically
i tried tawk.to but it doesnt have translator

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
